# Incrementitng PHP variable on form submit

Tags: php, sql-server

I'm trying to create a page where users can pass through values in a SQL-Server database table. I'm connected to the database through PHP but I'm having trouble incrementing my f_counter variable when the 'next' button is clicked.

```
<?php
require('db.php'); // Bring in the database connection
include("auth.php");  // Make sure the user is logged in to an account

$f_array = array(); // Create the array of values for the WHERE statement

$sel_query = "SELECT fiche
              FROM test.dbo.[F_Globale]
              ORDER BY f ASC;";
$sel_result = sqlsrv_query($con, $sel_query) or die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true));
while($sel_row = sqlsrv_fetch_array($sel_result)) {
    array_push($f_array, $sel_row['f']);
}


if(isset($_POST['new']) && $_POST['new']==1)
{
    $ficheCount ++;
    echo 'fail';
}else{
    $ficheCount = 0;
    echo 'pass';
}

$sel_query = "SELECT *
              FROM test_2018.dbo.[F_Globale]
              WHERE f = ".$f_array[$fCount]."
              ORDER BY fiche ASC;";
$sel_result = sqlsrv_query($con, $sel_query) or die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true));
while($sel_row = sqlsrv_fetch_array($sel_result)) {
?>
```

My form is just a simple button. The html references values from the database in inputs (not shown), but, the values only update the first time I click the next button.

```
<form name="page_form" method="post" action="" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="hidden" name="new" value="1" />

    <td rowspan="2">    
        <button name="next" id="next" value="next" style="font-size: 20px;"><i class="fa fa-angle-right"></i></button>
    </td>
</form>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#page_form button").click(function (ev) {
        ev.preventDefault()
        if ($(this).attr("value") == "next") {
            $("#page_form").submit();
        }
    });
});
</script>
```

Can anyone here see what I'm doing wrong. It seems like my $ficheCount variable is being reset on every page load but I've checked all my code and it only gets set to 0 if $_POST['new'] is not set or $joe <> 0. Since I've added the echos (fail and pass) it appears the value shouldn't be getting reset.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks

Comment: You're not going to be able to intermingle JS and PHP like you are. The line where you set `<?php $joe = 0; ?>` happens right away on page load, not when the button is clicked. Also, if you want to send `$joe` along with the form, you'll need to put it in a hidden field and access it via `$_POST`

Comment: I can't tell what you're trying to do here - where are you using these counter variables?  I see at least 2 - `$qry_count` and `$ficheCount `. And yes,a PHP variable only exists during the lifecycle of a single request. Your counters will start over with every page refresh unless you persist them in somehow (sessions, database, file, etc)

Comment: @WillardSolutions is correct. Converted to a session variable and that worked. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Converting the code to include session variables for fiche count fixed the page as suggested by @WillardSolutions.

```
session_start();

$fiche_array = array();


$sel_query = "SELECT f
              FROM test.dbo.[F_Globale]
              ORDER BY fiche ASC;";
$sel_result = sqlsrv_query($con, $sel_query) or die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true));
while($sel_row = sqlsrv_fetch_array($sel_result)) {
    array_push($fiche_array, $sel_row['f']);
 }

if(isset($_POST['new']) && $_POST['new']==1)
{
    $_SESSION['ficheCount'] ++;
    echo 'fail';
}else{
    $_SESSION['ficheCount'] = 0;
    echo 'pass';
}

$sel_query = "SELECT *
              FROM test.dbo.[F_Globale]
              WHERE fiche = ".$fiche_array[$_SESSION['ficheCount']]."
              ORDER BY f ASC;";
$sel_result = sqlsrv_query($con, $sel_query) or die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true));
while($sel_row = sqlsrv_fetch_array($sel_result)) {
```